# function applied to summarise + group_by doesn't work correctly

Tags: r, function, group-by, summarize

I extract my data

```
fluo <- read.csv("data/ctd_SOMLIT.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I display in three columns : the day, the month and the year based on the original date : Y - m - d

```
fluo$day <- day(as.POSIXlt(fluo$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
fluo$month <- month(as.POSIXlt(fluo$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
fluo$year <- year(as.POSIXlt(fluo$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

This is a part of my data_frame:

[image: data.frame]

Then, I do summarise and group_by in order to apply the function :

```
prof_DCM = fluo[max(fluo$FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence.),2]
```

=> I want the depth of the max of FLUORESCENCE measured for each month, for each year.

```
mean_fluo <- summarise(group_by(fluo, month, year), 
                       prof_DCM = fluo[max(fluo$FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence.),2])
mean_fluo <- arrange(mean_fluo, year, month)
View(mean_fluo)
```

But it's not working ... 
The values of prof_DCM still the same all along the column 3 of the data_frame:

[image: same value for column 3]

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
mean_fluo <- fluo %>%
group_by(month,year) %>%
filter(FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence. == max(FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence.)) %>%
arrange(year,month)

View(mean_fluo)
```

You can select the variables you want to keep with 'select'

```
mean_fluo <- fluo %>%
group_by(month,year) %>%
filter(FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence. == max(FLUORESCENCE..Fluorescence.)) %>%
arrange(year,month)%>%
select(c(month,year,PROFONDEUR))
```

Comment: Yes it works !  But it displays the max of the fluoroscence

Comment: Thank you for your answer Micky. Yes it works ! But it displays the max of the fluoroscence and I want the DEPTH of the max of the fluorescence

Comment: ah, I see. a moment

Comment: Use 'filter' to select rows based on a condition.